# Measuring GC cost in a fragmented heap - Haskell

Tags: haskell, garbage-collection, ghc

I am trying to benchmark fragmentation tolerance in haskell for an experiment.  I fill the heap up with small arrays and then deallocate every alternate one. I then try to allocate a large array of size equivalent to the size of the holes created by the deallocation and time this allocation. The outcome of this is to show that in a constrained heap setting, the cost of GCing is higher and more unpredictable than when there is a lot more free space on the heap. My code is as below. I use the large IO array of `SmallObj` to keep track of the small arrays which makes sure they are not optimized away and also makes it easier to deallocate every alternate one.

```
import Data.Array as AR
import Data.Array.IO as MA
import Control.Monad
import GHC.Stats
import System.Mem
import System.Environment
import System.IO
import Data.Time.Clock.POSIX

data SmallObj = SmallArray (IOArray Int Int) | Void
allocateArray num = do
    smallarr <- MA.newArray (1,2) num
    return smallarr

--fillHeap :: Int -> IO (IOArray Int (Maybe (IO(IOArray Int Int))))
fillHeap n = do
    temparr <- MA.newArray(1,2) 10
    let tempsarr = SmallArray (temparr)
    arr <- MA.newArray (1,n) tempsarr :: IO (IOArray Int SmallObj)
    traverseArray arr 1 n
    return arr


traverseArray arr n size
    | n <= size = do
                    smallarr <- allocateArray n
                    let ssmallarr = SmallArray (smallarr)
                    MA.writeArray arr n ssmallarr
                    traverseArray arr (n+1) size
    | otherwise = return arr

treadArray arr n size
    | n<=size = do
            b <- readArray arr n
            treadArray arr (n+1) size
    | otherwise = return ()

goThroughArray arr n size
    | n<=size = do
            b <- readArray arr n
            goThroughArray arr (n+1) size
    | otherwise = return ()

fragmentHeap lref n size
    | n <= size = do 
                          writeArray lref n Void
                          fragmentHeap lref (n+2) size
    | otherwise = return lref

putProgress :: Int -> IO ()
putProgress s = hPutStr stdout $ "\r\ESC[K" ++ show s

main = do
    args <- getArgs
    let size = read $ args!!0 :: Int -- 233570
    putStrLn "fillHeap"
    arr <- fillHeap size
    putStrLn "fragmentHeap"
    arr <- fragmentHeap arr 2 size
    putStrLn "\nmake small array"
    stats <- getGCStats
    putStrLn $ "Bytes allocated " ++ show(currentBytesUsed stats)
    tStart <- getPOSIXTime
    arr2 <- MA.newArray(1,1832957) 10 :: IO (IOUArray Int Int)
    tStop <- getPOSIXTime
    putStrLn $ "took " ++ show (tStop - tStart)
    treadArray arr2 1 1832957
    goThroughArray arr 1 size    
    stats <- getGCStats
    putStrLn $ "Bytes allocated " ++ show(currentBytesUsed stats)
    putStrLn ("done")
```

The issue i am facing is that the time taken to allocate the large array on the fragmented heap is almost the same irrespective the amount of free space available. I pin the heap size to 32 megs initially and all the sizes of arrays are the max possible size to fill the heap. On increasing the heap size by ten megs each time keeping the size of array allocated same, the amount of time taken to allocate the large array on a fragmented(supposedly) heap does not reduce as one would expect.  Here are some sample outputs:

```
./fragger2 233570 +RTS -T -M32477184 -RTS                                                                                   
fillHeap
fragmentHeap

make small array
Bytes allocated 31596064
took 0.004635s
Bytes allocated 31511432
done
```

And when i increase the initial heap size by about 10 MB

```
./fragger2 233570 +RTS -T -M42477184 -RTS                                                                                     
fillHeap
fragmentHeap
make small array
Bytes allocated 17522368
took 0.004519s
Bytes allocated 31511432
done
```

Being relatively new to Haskell I would like to know if I am measuring the time right and if the array allocation being a monadic operation affects the timing in any way , which is why I get the same allocation time irrespective of the free space on the heap?

Comment: I'd recommend using [criterion](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/criterion) for benchmarks like that. `getPOSIXTime` is a system call which can be expensive, therefore isn't a reliable way for measuring how long a very fast computation will take.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that "large" objects get allocated in a dedicated special area, rather than going on the regular generational heap.

Comment: Alexey I did look at the criterion benchmarks. Im having issues with typing as  the function i want to benchmark is of type    `(i, i) -> e -> IO (a i e)` and whnf or nf is of type    `(a->b)->a->benchmarkable`. It complains that I cant give it a function with 3 arguments. Moreover the [time](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/criterion-0.8.0.1/docs/Criterion-Measurement.html) function in Criterion.Measurement is apparently obsolete

Comment: MathematicalOrchid, even if large objects are allocated in an older gen like in quite a few generational GC allocation models, woudn't there be enough free allocation blocks for haskell  to resize the gen it is allocating the large object to (mentioned as an advantage of a block structured heap)? This should reduce the mutator pause time and there fore decrease time to allocate the object, right?